# How to activate dark theme of Windows 10/11 system settings in SWT applications?

Tags: java, windows, swt, darkmode

What do I need to do to make an SWT application use the dark theme / dark mode of system settings in Windows 10 or 11? I couldn't do it with SWT 3.122.0 (Win32 x86_64) from Maven repository.

I tried out to set a system property which is recommended here (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=540357):

`System.setProperty("org.eclipse.swt.display.useSystemTheme", "true");`

But it didn't work.

But it seems to me that the dark theme under Windows is not supported yet in SWT if I understand the information on these forums correctly:

- https://github.com/eclipse-platform/eclipse.platform.ui/issues/246
- https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&goto=1852115

Can you confirm that dark theme does not work for SWT under Windows yet or did I confuse anything?

Comment: you are using an old branch of SWT. Try first with the latest release.

Comment: @aled: Now I have updated to SWT Maven version 3.124.100 which is the current version of Win32 x86_64. The dark theme is still not used by my SWT application. Do you suppose that Win32 x86_64 is the wrong branch and I should try another one?

Comment: Try SWT 4.x. you are using 3.x which is an older branch.

Comment: If I follow on the SWT web page (https://www.eclipse.org/swt/) the link for the Maven artifact of Windows, I get only to this branch. Version 3.124.100 has been the current version for two months now. I think, a version 4.x is not available via Maven.
Now I have integrated SWT 4.29 for Windows (https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.29-202309031000/) without Maven. Still the dark theme is not working when I start the application.

Comment: @aled 3.124.100 is the SWT plug-in version in Eclipse 4.29 which corresponds to SWT version 4962r3 which is the current version of SWT.

Comment: These links maybe useful: https://eclipse.dev/eclipse/news/4.16/platform_isv.php#win-dark-tweaks, https://github.com/eclipse-platform/eclipse.platform.ui/issues/246

Comment: @greg-449: Thanks for clarification. Do you know a mapping of SWT maven / plug-in versions and Eclipse SDK versions?

Comment: @aled: Thanks, I did not know the news page of Eclipse SDK versions. It seems to be very useful, not only regarding SWT.
The dark theme tweaks work. But for example the window background color is kept the same. It confirms to me that dark theme is not completely supported currently. But perhaps it will in the future.

Comment: I don't know of a published table, I am looking at the SWT source code to get the versions.